# Increment the value if it exists, else add a new entry in DynamoDB

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, amazon-dynamodb

I have a DynamoDB table with columns and primary key as `ipAddress`:

- ipAddress
- visits

I am fetching the IP address of the user from my react website and inserting it to DynamoDB via a Lambda function and API Gateway POST request.

If the IP address coming from the React website is already present in the DynamoDB, then increment the value in `visits` column. If not, then create a new record with the new IP address and `visits = 1`. I tried using *ConditionExpression* but to no avail.

So far, I am only inserting the ipAddress using Lambda. Below is my Lambda function in NodeJS:

```
const AWS = require("aws-sdk");
const documentClient = new AWS.DynamoDB.DocumentClient();

exports.handler = async event => {
  const { ipAddress} = JSON.parse(event.body);
  const params = {
    TableName: "ipAddress",
    Item: {
      ipAddress: ipAddress,
    }
  };

  try {
    const data = await documentClient.put(params).promise();
    const response = {
      statusCode: 200,
    };
    return response;
  }
  catch (e) {
    return {
      statusCode: 500,
      body: JSON.stringify(e)
    };
  }

};
```

Answer (score 17, accepted):

We need to use [update-item](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/APIReference/API_UpdateItem.html#DDB-UpdateItem-request-UpdateExpression) rather than [put-item](https://awscli.amazonaws.com/v2/documentation/api/latest/reference/dynamodb/put-item.html), both creates a record if record doesn't exist. But update-item accepts [UpdateExpression](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/APIReference/API_UpdateItem.html#DDB-UpdateItem-request-UpdateExpression) to help us update an existing attribute.

`UpdateExpression: "SET visits = if_not_exists(visits, :initial) + :num"`

`if_not_exists` helps to use `initial` value for the first time when attributes `visits` doesn't exist.

```
docClient.update(
  {
    TableName: "ipAddress",
    Key: {
      ipAddress: ipAddress,
    },
    UpdateExpression: "SET visits = if_not_exists(visits, :initial) + :num",
    ExpressionAttributeValues: {
      ":num": 1,
      ":initial": 0,
    },
  },
  function (error, result) {
    console.log("error", error, "result", result);
  }
);
```