# Increment a number in dynamoDB

Tags: javascript, node.js, amazon-dynamodb, dynamodb-queries

I want to increment a number value 'count' in dynamoDB.
The problem I've is that I'm not sure if the key (pk,sk) actually exists.

```
for a given <pk,sk>
 - if <pk,sk,count> exists increment it by 1
 - if it is not exists add <pk,sk, count = 0>
```

I can do it in two separate queries but can it done in the same request?

Thanks,
Omer

Comment: This is answered here https://stackoverflow.com/a/66308829/7793122

Comment: @derpirscher Thanks, This really helped me. I tried to search for it in google\stackoverflow and couldn't find it.

Comment: By the way, @omer727, one potential correction to your question: usually if the item doesn't exist you want to set its count to 1, not to 0 as you said in your question (in other words, it's like you initialized it to 0 and then incremented it normally).

Comment: I'm a developer I'm starting to count at 0 not at 1. :)
But yes, you are right of course.

Comment: The "Counting Numbers" set starts at 1.